# How do I change the visibility of a gui with a script?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make it so that when you click a certain object a text box appears and the text is different depending on what you clicked, but for some reason it won't work. I think it is because I am incorrectly specifying the GUI, but I don't know how to do it properly.

I have tried changing the StarterGui and PlayerGui, but neither seems to be working. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Also, the game is singleplayer, so it doesn't need to be specified to only affect one person.

```
local Box = game.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.TextBox

local function onClick(playerWhoClicked)
    game.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.Enabled = true
    if workspace.Clues.test.Value == 1
    then
    Box.Text = "Your masters words echo in your head: wi can has can, but wi can't has this yet"
    wait (5)
    game.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.Enabled = false
    else
    Box.Text = "Filipe has been murdered??!?!?"
    wait (5)
    game.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.Enabled = false
    end
    end

script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(onClick)
```

I'm fairly sure there is a way to do this, I just can't figure out how

Comment: You're referencing `game.PlayerGui` which is does not reference the local player's UI. The player's UI is referenced from `game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui` and can only be accessed like such from a LocalScript.

Comment: This answer should work for your problem too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813667/remove-a-screengui-when-unequipping/55819879#55819879